# How to import PDF file with react-file-viewer in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to use file-viewer in Next.js, but I get this error:

> ./public/pdf.pdf Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You may
> need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no
> loaders are configured to process this file. See 
> > %PDF-1.3 
> | %���� 
> |

How can I solve this problem?

my code:

```
import FileViewer from "react-file-viewer/src/components";
import pdf from "../../../public/pdf.pdf"

...(in component)

 {openFileViewer ? <FileViewer fileType="pdf" filePath={pdf}  /> : null}
```

Comment: You can't import PDFs like modules. Have you tried passing the path directly in the `filePath` prop? I guess you can also pass `pdf.pdf` in the prop directly, as it is in the public folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your PDF file is located in the `public` folder, you can reference the image's path directly in the `filePath` prop.

You also need to make sure `react-file-viewer` is only imported in the browser as it depends on `window` being present to work properly. You can do so by dynamically importing the component through `next/dynamic` with `ssr: false`.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const FileViewer = dynamic(() => import('react-file-viewer'), {
    ssr: false
});

export default function Index() {
    return (
        <FileViewer fileType="pdf" filePath="/pdf.pdf" />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You still can import a `.pdf` file in Next.js without the need to a third party module, simply by using `<iframe>` HTML tag instead.

If you uploaded your file on a cloud storage; say google drive, dropbox, S3 ..etc
you can embed its link in your website as such:

```
const PreviewFile = () => {
  return (
    <iframe
      src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/11h3WlhD221wMuXyXWPsdmXb4UNM-qaot/preview"
      title="Async & Performance"
      width="800"
      height="600"
    />
  )
}
```

*Note that a google drive link is used here but it's an **embed link** not the one you get when you click on **share** button.
as attached below:

[image: embed item preview] [image]