# FileViewer in Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to open files (doc, excel, pdf...) with react-file-viewer... in React it works, but in Next.js doesn't work... error: ReferenceError: window is not defined

```
import React from "react";
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import FileViewer from "react-file-viewer";

const file = "./pdf.pdf";
const type = "pdf";

const onError = e => {
    console.log(e, "error in file-viewer");
};


export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1>React File Viewer Demo</h1>
      <h2>Displaying file with extension {type}</h2>
      <FileViewer fileType={type} filePath={file} onError={onError} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [How to import PDF file with react-file-viewer in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68350541/1870780)?

Comment: thanks, now it works. But please help me with one more question. when I call the component right away - everything is ok but when I call it with a condition - it doesn't work

{ viewModal ? <FileViewer ... /> : null}

Comment: Is the `viewModal` condition `true` when you try to render the `FileViewer`? You may want to create a new question and provide more details, as that goes beyond the scope of the current issue.